# Completed 302 Found only in Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

When I do a query with Chrome, it shows me the default exception page on Rails.

And I looked up the Rails log, it shows me the `Completed 302` without any detailed clue.

My environments are based on Nginx, Puma, AWS ELB

```
Redirected to https://lazyair.co/flights/index?end_date=2016-05-18&from=TAIPEI&start_date=2016-05-13&to=NAGOYA
Completed 302 Found in 11ms
Cache write: _session_id:901205aab7086083365c060e437ee91f ({:expires_in=>1 month})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding these lines in nginx.conf

However, I don't know the reason.

```
    proxy_buffers 8 16k;
    proxy_buffer_size 32k;
```

## nginx.conf

```
    location @sample_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://sample_app;
        proxy_cache lazyair_cache;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10s;
        proxy_read_timeout 30s;
        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_buffers 8 16k;
        proxy_buffer_size 32k;
    }
```